# Does hydrolysis of carbohydrates, proteins, and fats occur in the small intestine?

Tags: proteins, digestion, carbohydrates

Does the hydrolysis of carbohydrates, proteins, and fats occur in the small intestine? I have researched this and just cannot seem to get a clear-cut answer. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

**Any help and/or links to resources are appreciated!** I just want to make sure that I understand this concept before moving on with other biology topics that I am learning.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you've learned and where exactly your understanding is lacking?

Comment: @BryanKrause I am not sure if I _am_ lacking any understanding. I am taking high school bio, and I have been learning about the digestive system. So, I am not sure if hydrolysis of carbohydrates, proteins, and fats occur in the small intestine.

Comment: That's fine, but according to our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) we require that questions show their own research effort (not just state that the effort happened). This is part of how we avoid people asking questions here to just fill in the answers on their assignments, which we feel damages rather than assists learning.

Comment: @BryanKrause You know, I really appreciate that. I am so over the cheating nowadays because now I have to show proof of my research rather than just you trusting me (one bad apple spoils the bunch). Then again, I appreciate you taking the precautions. :) [This is where I was finding my information,](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ap/chapter/chemical-digestion/) but I did not find what I was looking for...

Comment: digestion doesn't only happen in small intestine, but also in stomach and mouth even. search for what hydrolysis exactly means, then search for where do hydrolysis reactions happen in body, then search for digestion of carbohydrates, lipids and proteins and how do they happen.

Comment: @manidattas Thank you for your help! After some other research, I feel like hydrolysis of all three compounds does occur in the small intestine. I hope that I am understanding everything correctly; appreciate it. :)

Comment: [This article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancreas#Digestion) should give you enough terms and anatomy to answer your question the way you asked it. Once you know some names, look up the enzymes in other sources - you can *use* Wikipedia, but you can't *trust* it.  (Then try submitting an answer to your own question to help solidify your knowledge!)